# Loading data from webservice in UitableView

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have TableView with custom cell. Now I want to populate my tableView with data coming form webService. I am saving my data in NSUserDefaults after getting from webservice. And then fetching from userDefaults to my array named "dataArray"

Now when I try to populate it in cellForRowAtIndexPath it show error because dataArray is not populated yet. Lets say If it take 2 seconds to fetch data from webService, save it in userDefaults and then populate my array. Then How can I populate my tableView after 2 seconds and not before that ?

Please help thanks.

Comment: Did you call `tableView.reloadData()` after fetch data?

Comment: I do but what should I do when first time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called ?

Comment: In **numberOfRowsInSection** method return array count from userdefault. At first array count will be **0** so it wont come to **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.One after fetching data reload the tableview by **tableView.reloadData()**.Now there will be some count,then everything will be ok.

Comment: I do not want my tableView to popuate anything before my array get the data

Comment: if **numberOfRowsInSection** is 0 **(i.e array count from user default before getting service respoce is always 0 if u clear userdefault after every use.)** it wont load anything in your tableview.

Comment: You should declared array as empty like var dataArray:[String] = []

Answer (score 0):

1- create array and in  `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
return array.count;
```

2-after you get data from web service populate it to your array and used `tableView.reloadData()`

3- check that you used the correct tableView and correct Cell Identifier and establish uitableview delegate and datasource to you app.
I hope I help you.